# incrementing the count in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently working on an assignment for my SQL class and i'm having a little trouble. For the one part of my assignment it asks "Count the number of orders that currently exist and list all the orders data in descending order starting with the most recent order date." I am able to use the count function, and also am able to display all data but separately. When I try to run the query with all the code together, it displays all the data but for the count it shows 9 rows of 1 when the count should equal 9. 
code

```
SELECT COUNT(ORDER_NUMBER), ORDER_NUMBER, ORDER_DATE, CUSTOMER_NUMBER
FROM ORDERS
GROUP BY ORDER_NUMBER, ORDER_DATE, CUSTOMER_NUMBER
ORDER BY ORDER_DATE DESC
```

[image]

Comment: Please share the expected output too!! Your count will always give 1 as you are grouping the result based on the ORDER_NUMBER also

Comment: try removing `ORDER_NUMBER` from the select `COUNT(ORDER_NUMBER), ORDER_NUMBER, ORDER_DATE, CUSTOMER_NUMBER`, but not the **count**!
And remove ORDER_NUMBER from the group `GROUP BY ORDER_NUMBER, ORDER_DATE, CUSTOMER_NUMBER` too!

Comment: I don't have a picture of the expected output as professor did not provide one.  From the wording of the assignment, it appears hes looking for the total count of the rows, then wants all data from the table listed in descending order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the trick with grouping; to count things up you need to lose the detail, but if you then try to get the detail back by splitting the group down into smaller chunks it doesn't have as many items in each group any more.

This means you either have to have two queries, one that groups and one that gives detail, then join them together:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
  orders o
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT count(*) as ct FROM orders GROUP BY customer_number) g
  ON o.customer_number = g.customer_number
```

Or you can use an analytical function, which conceptually does the same thing but is a bit more advanced usage (might not have been taught yet):

```
SELECT 
  o.*,
  COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY customer_number) as ct
FROM
  orders o
```

Note; I've got no idea what columns you actually want to count and group on; I picked customer number here because I know it exists - these queries will give the count of orders for each customer plus all the detail of them. Your basic technique for using GROUP BY is to decide on some columns that you want to count every unique variation of (like if you wanted to know how many employees per department you would group on department_id because if there are 50 employees equally split across 10 departments the department_id column should have 10 different if numbers in, each number repeating 5 times - GROUP BY would produce a result set of 10 rows one for each different department ID and COUNT would produce 5 on every row because that is how many rows before were collapsed into one row now)

If you wanted to eg count all orders in the system you can do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
  orders o
  CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT count(*) as ct FROM orders) g
```

We have to use a cross join here because we don't have any columns we join on any more- the subquery just calculates a single result that we want to appear on every row and that is what cross join does: connects every row on the left with every row on the right

```
SELECT 
  o.*,
  COUNT(*) OVER() as ct
FROM
  orders o
```

Also note that your assignment asks for the rows to output in a particular order. I haven't done that part, but I'll leave it as an exercise for you - don't forget it because it's part of the spec and will be marked

Answer (score 1):

use "**count(*)ORDER_NUMBER**" instead of what you are using